# object-literal-sort-keys needs type info to use "match-declaration-order" or "match-declaration-order-only"

Tags: typescript, tslint

In my `tslint.json` I have `object-literal-sort-keys` defined as `match-declaration-order`:

```
{
  "defaultSeverity": "error",
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended"
  ],
  "jsRules": {},
  "rules": {
    "no-console": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": [
      true,
      "match-declaration-order"
    ],
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      200
    ],
    "typedef": [
      true,
      "member-variable-declaration",
      "variable-declaration"
    ]
  },
  "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

However I'm always getting this error:

```
object-literal-sort-keys needs type info to use "match-declaration-order" or
"match-declaration-order-only".
See https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/type-checking/ for documentation on
how to enable this feature.
```

I have tried the examples shown in the [documentation](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/type-checking/), but they don't solve the issue. The only thing removing this error is to use the `object-literal-sort-keys` default setting, but then I have to alphabetically sort all arrays.

How do I have to configure `object-literal-sort-keys` to make this error go away?

Comment: Is this error happening as part of a build process, or when running a command such as `yarn lint` or `npm run lint`? If so, which build tool are you using (e.g. webpack, parcel)?

Comment: As part of a build process when running `npx tslint --fix -c tslint.json 'src/**/*{.ts,.tsx}'`. It's not a web application, it's for parsing excel files to yml. So there is no build tool behind it. To run it I call `npx tsc; npx node parser.js;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `"match-declaration-order"` for the [object-literal-sort-keys](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/object-literal-sort-keys/) rule requires tslint to have type information, since it needs to check  object literal against their defined type. To be able to this, tslint needs to know of the `tsconfig.json` file used in the same application. This can be provided as a flag, either `--project` or `--p`. The complete command will look like this:

```
npx tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json
```

This will lint every file that would be compiled for the project.

Comment: Ah so that's where the type information is hidden. Thanks!